# Passing argument to all Rails translations without modifying all translation calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

Passing an argument to a single translation is easy (from guides):

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%=t 'greet_username', :user => "Bill", :message => "Goodbye" %>

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
```

[edit] Is it possible to pass an argument to all translations without the need to modify all translation calls? so I could use %{my_variable} in all translations but the argument would be passed only once, like a global translation argument

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%=t 'greet_username', :my_variable=> "Bill Goodbye" %>

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  greet_username: "%{my_variable} !"
```